# FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a simple collection reference in a service

```js
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
          this.itineraryCollection = firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection(`itinerary/${user.uid}/itineraryList`);
        }
      });
```

I'm calling this service OnInit

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedInUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.dataSvc.getItineraries()
    .get()
    .then( itineraryListSnapshot => {
      this.itineraries = [];
      itineraryListSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
        this.itineraries.push({
          id: snap.id,
          activities: snap.data().activities,
          destination: snap.data().destination,
          startDate: snap.data().startDate,
          endDate: snap.data().endDate,
          tripDetails: snap.data().tripDetails,
          userId: snap.data().userId
        });
      });
    });

    // this.itineraries = this.dataSvc.getUserItinerary();
    console.log('logged in user add itin page', this.itineraries);
  }
```

But I keep getting the following error on page initialization:

```js
vendor.js:49548 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new FirestoreError (vendor.js:76086)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromRpcStatus (vendor.js:81385)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromWatchChange (vendor.js:81882)
    at PersistentListenStream.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.PersistentListenStream.onMessage (vendor.js:90087)
    at vendor.js:90016
    at vendor.js:90056
    at vendor.js:83144
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.js:2749)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:51123)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.js:2748)
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:3189)
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:3146)
    at polyfills.js:3250
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:2781)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:51114)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:2780)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (polyfills.js:2553)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.js:2959)
    at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (polyfills.js:2860)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (polyfills.js:2845)
```

I'm not sure what my database rules in firebase should be but I've tried a bunch of different rules:

```js
      match /itinerary/{userId} {
            allow read; 
            allow write;
      }
      
            match /itinerary/{userId}/itineraryList {
            allow read; 
            allow write;
      }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 29, accepted):

add this to your Database Rules tab :

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This should only be used for testing, as it would allow for any client to write.

Comment: that's only for testing purpose. DO NOT USE IT FOR A PROD without a condition

Comment: @dwoodwardgb If i was going to have a comments section, on a blog for example, where anyone can comment, would this not be the best way to go about it?

Comment: Typical Angular developers, tsk

Comment: Don't use this solution, anyone can access your collection with this rule

Answer (score 7):

Try changing the rule to:

```
match /itinerary/{userId}/itineraryList/{doc} {
  allow read, write: if true;
}
```

Be aware, the if condition of 'true' is just for testing, as it allows everyone permission to that resource. I only suggest it here for to test the rule works.

Adding `/{doc}` to the match - allows the rule to be applied to the documents you are protecting.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this by changing the rules of the database to the reading allowed for anyone, but leaving the methods of creating, changing, deleting and updating only for connected users. The commented part is for a later implementation where you have already defined administrator rules for each user logged in, so you can pass there that only users who are administrators can change.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow create, update, delete, write: if request.auth != null;
      //allow create, update, delete, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userIdAdmin;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem with an "**undefined**" document id. I checked my firestore rules and they didn't seem to cause any harm.
**A Typo did**.

```
removeTask(boardId: string, task: Task) {
  return this.db
   .collection('boards')
   .doc(booardId) // <-- here, it has to be "boardId" instead
   .update({
      tasks: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(task),
   })
   .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err); //TODO: handle that exception properly  
   });
 }
```

and my firestore rules look like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow create: if requestMatchesUID(); 
      allow update: if resourceMatchesUID() && requestMatchesUID();
      allow delete: if resourceMatchesUID()
    }
 
    function requestMatchesUID(){
      return request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.uid;
    }    

    function resourceMatchesUID(){
      return request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid; 
    }
   }
 }
```

for the rules, checkout [fireship](https://fireship.io/courses/angular/kanban-firestore-data/)